# How can I create a for loop for dataframes with different names from a folder of xlsx files?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I create a for loop for dataframes with different names? [python]
I need to read few xlsx files from a folder and for each of them do some for loops with some calculus on the data of each file.

I kinda know how to read a folder of files. What I would like is that for each of them the code create a dataframe, do the calculus of the code I've already wrote about a generic one and save the results in a xlsx output file so for each I'd have: output1.xlsx, output2.xlsx etc. While looping on the files of the folder how can I associate the index of the loop to the argument of the loops of my calculus and to the last line where I save my output in a xlsx file.
Hoping I made the problem clear, thanks to everyone willing to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question -

You can list the files on that directory, and then you can get the names of the files using `split()` and store them in a dictionary with `file_name as key` and `values as dataframe` -

```
df_dict = {}

for file in list_files:
    file_name = file.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]

    df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
    
    df_dict[file_name] = df
```

To associate the index, you can use `enumerate()` -

```
for i, file in enumerate(list_files):
    out_file_name = f"output{i}.xlsx"
    df.to_excel(out_file_name)
```